# AngularFire objects

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been playing with AngularFire, and I understand the documentation for collections.  But I feel like I'm totally missing things when it comes to loading specific items inside the collection, by anything besides position in the array.

All of the examples in the Firebase data have pretty names for the api like user/name/first

But when I use angularFireCollection to save a collection I get my object inside a unique $id.  (not as pretty)

Is that the expected behavior?  And if so, how would I get() an item based on a value instead?

ex.  I created a key called slug.  That has 'my-theme' in the collection.  And I want to load it by $routeParams.

```
.when('/themes/:slug/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/theme.html',
    controller: 'ThemesCtrl'
  })
```

How would I load an object into themes/my-theme instead of themes/-J50neNBViK9l7P4QAYc

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I abandoned AngularFire for using the Firebase javascript API, it worked perfect.  Using set() instead of push().  It should be noted that its only okay to do that if there's no chance of duplicating IDs though...

Answer (score 1):

angularFireCollection automatically creates a list of items with auto-generated incremental IDs (generated by Firebase's push() method). If you want to create a list of items with custom names, angularFire might be a better service to use (it uses set instead of push). For example:

```js
function ThemesCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
  $scope.themes = {};
  angularFire(new Firebase(URL), $scope, 'themes');
  $scope.addTheme = function() {
    $scope.themes["my-theme"] = $scope.currentTheme;
  }
}
```